# Data not writing to Firebase Database using Unity using SetRawJson

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

```
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    reference.Child("users").Child(newUser.UserId).SetValueAsync(JsonUtility.ToJson(email));
```

This code isn't writing anything to the database and these are my database rules.

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
}
```

The code is called after a user has signed up with email, and the sign up part is working. I have tried in the unity editor, an android emulator, and a physical android device. Still nothing is being written to the database.